# Find equation of the straight line tangent to the curve at the point indicated

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find equation of the straight line tangent to the curve at the point indicated:

$y=2x^2 -5$ at $(2,3)$

I think I have to use $y=m(x-x_o)+y_0$ etc but I'm not sure how to find the $m$! Thanks for tips/solutions!

Comment: You've tagged this as calculus; what relevance do you see to that subject?

Comment: $m = \frac{dy}{dx}|_{x = 2}$.

Comment: limits? or something?

Comment: @qwerty123123 Are you familiar with something called the 'derivative'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=2x^2-5$$
We can differentiate this equation to give us the slope, $m$.
$$m=4x$$
If we input our $x$ value of $2$, we should get $m=8$ at $(2,3)$. We can now use the general equation for a line using the values for $m$ and from the point $(x_1,y_1)$.
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
$$y-3=8(x-2)$$
This gives us our final answer for the tangent line.
$$y=8x-13$$

Comment: I'd suggest that you reconsider giving such complete solutions to questions like this - rather, leave a hint and try to lead the asker to the solution. Just spoonfeeding an answer is rather harmful, I feel.

Comment: @T.Bongers Yeah, you have a point although I quite enjoy writing out solutions. But I'll take your advice and give hints as that does seem more sensible.

Comment: ahh ok thanks for the answer! I tought I had to use some limit stuff with h etc solve it for slope, so I was kinda confused :)